# How to change the default tailwind font-family in nuxtjs3

Tags: localization, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I created a Nuxt3 project and installed `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` package. I want to set my favorite font as default. I read the tailwind documentation, but I didn't understand where the problem is that the font is not set as default.

my tailwind config :

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Montserrat',...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      },
  },
};
```

my font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('./Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    url('./Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.at first register `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` in nuxt.config.ts|js by putting module array.

2.back to the project and create `main.css` in this directory => `assets/css/main.css` then import your font in this file like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   src: url('../css/Font/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

3.then register this file in Nuxt configuration by adding `css` property:

```
// nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.css',
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
});
```

4.then change your tailwind configuration to this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif']
            }
        },

    },
}
```